# Google Admin Directory API, bad request 400 invalid_grant. (using service account)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, bad-request, service-accounts, client-library

So before showing my code, let me explain what steps I took to 'properly' set up service account environment.

1. In google developer console, created service account. (this produced Client ID (which is a long number), Service account (xxxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com), and private key which I downloaded in P12.
2. In Admin console, put the client ID with appropriate scope. In my case the scopes I added is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly`.
3. In my code, correctly set up private key path and other environments.

   ```
   def getDirectoryService: Directory = {
     val httpTransport: HttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport()
     val jsonFactory: JacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory()
     val credential: GoogleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
       .setTransport(httpTransport)
       .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
       .setServiceAccountId("xxxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
       .setServiceAccountScopes(util.Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_READONLY, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER_READONLY))
       .setServiceAccountUser("admin@domain.com")
       .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
         new java.io.File("/pathToKey/privatekey.p12"))
       .build()
     val service: Directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
       .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build()
     service
   }
   ```
4. And then I attempt to execute something like this:

   ```
   service.groups().list().execute()
   ```

or

```
    service.groups().list("domain.com").execute()
```

This code would result in,

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.company.project.GoogleServiceProvider.getGroups(GoogleServiceProvider.scala:81)
        at com.company.project.ProjectHandler.handle(ProjectHandler.scala:110)
        at com.company.common.web.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.scala:40)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could have I done wrong? I have been searching solution for past two days, and tried many things. One of the solutions I am not still not sure of is ntp syncing (as in how to exactly sync server time to ntp).

Any adivce would be very helpful, thank you!

UPDATE: I also made sure to activate the Admin Directory SDK, and enabled the Domain-Wide Delegation on developer's console.

UPDATE #2: I forgot to mention that, the admin account is not the owner of the project itself. So basically, I am a member of a domain, and I created a project, so I am the only owner of the project and the service account.(I am not the admin).  But should an admin be owner of the project and create service account in order for this to work properly???

Comment: have you tried setting setServiceAccountUser to the service account email address?

Comment: Shouldnt serviceAccountUser be an email address of a persom I am trying to impersonate? If I use service account email address for serviceAccountUser what do I put for serviceAccountId??

Comment: Service account is a dummy user itself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay btw!  So with my current set up, what should I put into serviceAccountId and serviceAccountUser? Right now, I am putting my service account's email address xxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com into serviceAccountId,  and admin@domain.com into serviceAccountUser.  Is it wrong?

Comment: Hey, I put second update on the original post: TLDR; admin is not the owner of the project and the service account. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my problem was that in `setServiceAccountUser` I put admin group email address, not the actual user account. Apparently, it doesn't allow putting in group email (alias) address into `setServiceAccountUser`. 
So after putting in an actual user account with admin privilege, it seems to be working.

I still wonder what would be the best practice though. As in, should I create a separate user account with admin privilege just for the project? I definitely don't want to just put in an admin account email address in my code.

Comment: I have seen this question a number of times unfortunately I don't have a Google admin account so I cant test it.   If what you did works stick with it :)